# Unable to install packages wbstats, plotly, tidyverse in Rstudio

Tags: r, plotly, tidyverse

As the question suggests, I'm trying to install these packages. However, I'm unable to import then in Rstudio.

```
## Installing required packages ##
install.packages("wbstats", dependencies = TRUE)#Error
install.packages(c("plotly", dependencies = TRUE))#Error
install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)#Error

library("wbstats")#Error
library("plotly")#Error
library("tidyverse")#Error
```

After I try to import them using the library() function,
[image: The following error pops up]

I have checked in the folder in which the packages are being installed, the files are present there.
[image: As seen here, the above mentioned packages can be seen.]

What can I do to import these packages in Rstudio?
Thank you

Comment: Use "quotes" for `install.packages()` function, and no quotes for `library(tidyverse)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotes when you going to install a package:

```
install.packages("fastDummies")
```

but when you just call a library you don't have to use quotes

```
library(fastDummies)
```

And that's all.

Comment: Tries what you suggested, but the error persists. Exact same error as before.